# Ejecutar una linea determinada dentro de una función

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una función con 8 posiciones de mouse (clicks), dependiendo del numero aleatorio que salga quiero que se ejecute esa linea de la función, por ejemplo en el random sale el 1 pues se ejecutaría pyautogui.click(432,403)#1

¿que me faltaría en la función para que funcione?

```
import random
import time
import pyautogui 

def clicks():
        pyautogui.click(729,444)#0
        pyautogui.click(432,403)#1
        pyautogui.click(532,479)#2
        pyautogui.click(280,477)#3
        pyautogui.click(528,403)#4
        pyautogui.click(230,439)#5
        pyautogui.click(632,480)#6
        pyautogui.click(477,438)#7
        pyautogui.click(779,480)#8  


while True:      

   numero=random.randint(0,8)

   clicks(numero)
   time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, necesitas pasar un argumento a la función para determinar que debe ejecutarse. En tu ejemplo lo pasas, pero la función no lo acepta.

Hecho esto generalmente lo normal sería usar condicionales simplemente, un bloque `if-elif-else`:

```
def clicks(num):
    if num == 0:
        pyautogui.click(729, 444)  #0
    elif num == 1:
        pyautogui.click(432, 403)  #1
    elif num == 2:
        pyautogui.click(532, 479)  #2
    elif num == 3:
        pyautogui.click(280, 477)  #3
    elif num == 4:
        pyautogui.click(528, 403)  #4
    elif num == 5:
        pyautogui.click(230, 439)  #5
    elif num == 6:
        pyautogui.click(632, 480)  #6
    elif num == 7:
        pyautogui.click(477, 438)  #7
    elif num == 8:
        pyautogui.click(779, 480)  #8
```

Otra opción más "bizarra"  es usar un diccionario de forma que cada valor del argumento se corresponda con una clave del mismo y su valor sea una referencia a la función a ejecutar y/o sus argumentos:

```
    def clicks(num):
        ops = {0: (729, 444), 1: (432, 403), 2: (532, 479), 3: (280, 477),
               4: (528, 403), 5: (230, 439), 6: (632, 480), 7: (477, 438),
               8: (779, 480)}
        if (args := ops.get(num)) is not None:
            pyautogui.click(*args)
```

No tiene mucha utilidad en este caso y hace la función algo menos eficiente pero es una técnica muy útil en otros casos. En este ejemplo, se podría también usar una tupla o otro contenedor indizable dado que el rango del argumento va de 0 a 8 podemos usarlo como índice:

```
def clicks(num):
    ops = ((729, 444), (432, 403), (532, 479), (280, 477), (528, 403),
           (230, 439), (632, 480), (477, 438), (779, 480))
    try:
        args = ops[num]
    except IndexError:
        return
    else:
        pyautogui.click(*args)
```